# Making a chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

First time poster and currently getting familiar with Google Spreadsheet with using some books and information on the net. However, I couldn't put into words what I was trying to do so I found this site.

I am trying to make a simple chart in Google Spreadsheet of whom attended  work without me having to fill in who came everyday. I want to use Google App Script or VBA or anything where I can eliminate

Here is a data table I am using, in a nutshell
⬇︎

```
id     name     date
001    John     2020/01/01
002    Mark     2020/01/01
003    Brad     2020/01/01
001    John     2020/01/02
002    Mark     2020/01/02
001    John     2020/01/03
002    Mark     2020/01/03
003    Brad     2020/01/03
```

Here is what I want to make

```
      2020/01/01    2020/01/02    2020/01/03
John     ◯             ◯             ◯
Mark     ◯             ◯             ◯
Brad     ◯                           ◯
```

Comment: Welcome. What does it means the circles in the example of what you want to make? Could that be represented with checked checkboxes?  Even if what you want to make it's possible to be done by using formulas or other Google Sheets built-in features ( like a pivot table) do you still want to use Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

Select your data and create a pivot table

[image]